# comparison operators precendence in Bison

Tags: comparison, bison

I'm trying to set rules for comparison operators :== <= !=, etc...
I already have this precendence list:

```
%nonassoc "=="
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right '^'
%left UNARY
```

the first line with == doesn't work. I guess it's because "==" isn't a character but a string, but I can't figure out hoe to do it otherwise.
It's supposed to be nonassoc, so that 1==2==3 will fail. thanks

Comment: You'll need to show a bit more of your bison grammar file in order to answer this question. In particular, please show the rule(s) which use the `"=="` token. Also, how is your lexer returning the token value which corresponds to `"=="`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you write, Bison doesn't understand `"=="`. You can use single-character tokens such as `'+'` directly, but for multi-character tokens you need to define them using Bison's `%token` directive. Then you must let the scanner return that token code.